# How do I call a function in javascript to call a solidity function using meteor and TemplateVar

Tags: solidity, remix, javascript, meteor

I have created a very simple front end to display the borrower name. I deployed the contract Borrower on Rinkeby. I can run the application if I access the variable borrowerName using the following .js code:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';

contractAddress = "0x7f3bdc7f93b0dfc1939669d35922d65bbc5953e4"

ABIArray = [
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getThisBalance",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getName",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "borrowerName",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_borrowerName",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    }
]

data = "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"

Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
  // counter starts at 0
  this.displayName = new ReactiveVar(0);
});


Template.hello.helpers({
  displayName() {
    var template = Template.instance();

    myContract = web3.eth.contract(ABIArray).at(contractAddress);

    myContract.borrowerName(function(err, res){
        TemplateVar.set(template, "displayName", res)
    });
  },
});
```

but if I replace borrowerName the variable with getName the function, it fails. The HTML code is as follows:

```
<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>Borrower Name {{displayName}} {{TemplateVar.get "displayName"}} </p>
</template>
```

I assume it is something simple I am missing but I would appreciate any help Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So I solved it. Quite simple actually once I figured it out... I simply needed to change the Java Script helper code as follows:

```
Template.hello.helpers({
  displayName() {
    var template = Template.instance();

    myContract = web3.eth.contract(ABIArray).at(contractAddress);

    myContract.getName(function(err, res){
        TemplateVar.set(template, "getName", res)
    });
  },
});
```

and the HTML code as follows:

```
<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>The name of the borrower is {{displayName}} {{TemplateVar.get "getName"}} </p>
</template>
```

The problem was with the get and set functions. I needed to reference the function getName.